# How does the orbital velocity of a satellite vary for distance between the surface of earth(nearly) and more?

Tags: satellites

My physics teacher told me its the same for any distance but the formula for orbital velocity is under root of Gm/R+H  so it must vary ?

Comment: Because $v$ is a function of the orbital radius, a change in the orbital radius will result in a change in orbital velocity.

Comment: I think your teacher meant that speed of the satellite in a CIRCULAR ORBIT doesn't change at  any point of the trajectory(It's not the case for example for an elliptic trajectory). It will of course vary for various radius but that means other trajectories.